# Lighthouse keeps showing Defer offscreen images

Tags: html, lighthouse

So every time I run lighthouse evaluation, it keeps telling me to "Defer offscreen images", now, what they recommend is to use their script and to set the images like this :

```
<img data-src="images/flower3.png" class="lazyload" alt="">
```

And this is what I have:

```
    <picture>
      <source sizes="(min-width:1025px) 25vw,(min-width:0px) 100vw" 
       srcset="https://thumbor.mypage/YiZprbZxOEdzieJbcj8ZnIKIrE4=/640x0/https%3A%2F%2Fmyimage.jpg 640w,...">
      <img alt="" sizes="(min-width:1025px) 25vw,(min-width:0px) 100vw" 
         data-object-fit="cover" 
         class=" ls-is-cached lazyloaded" 
         data-src="https://thumbor.mypage/yoi8S4dSPBIU5ekNg6x7NvFFFPM=/320x0/https%3A%2F%2Fmyimage.jpg" 
         srcset="https://thumbor.mypage/YiZprbZxOEdzieJbcj8ZnIKIrE4=/640x0/https%3A%2F%2Fmyimage.jpg 640w,https://thumbor.mypage/qoSnHcwy_fuA8C2gJaKnxnCJ00A=/1024x0/https%3A%2F%2Fmyimage.jpg 1024w,...">
    </picture>
```

So as you can see, I check the two things they ask for to match the right code: the lazyload class and the data-src attribute, maybe I'm missing something but for some reason, it only fails with a couple images. please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

The second an image has a `src` or `srcset` attribute set it will load the image. You need to use a lazy load library that supports the `<picture>` element and make sure you haven't set the `src` or `srcset` on your `<picture>` elements.

### Long Answer

You have misunderstood a key aspect here. The `class="lazyload"` and `data-src="images/flower3.png"` are part of [a lazy load solution using JavaScript](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes). You can't just copy these attributes without the related JavaScript code.

With their example ([which I assume is this example of lazy loading](https://web.dev/codelab-use-lazysizes-to-lazyload-images/) as you did not link it in your question) there is a script you must include in order to make lazy loading work.

If you look at their example these `<img>` elements do not have a `src` attribute set and so they are invalid and will not load the image.

What the script does is look for `<img>` elements that have a class of `lazyload` and then look for the `data-src` attribute.

It then takes whatever is in the `data-src` attribute and adds that to the `src` attribute of the image once the image is within the viewport.

This then makes the image valid (as an `<img>` element **must** have a `src` attribute to be valid and actually load the image) and so it loads.

In your example you already have the `src` set via the `srcset` attribute in your HTML so the images are loaded instantly, the `data-src` does nothing in this case.

I am not sure whether the lazy loading library in that example works with `<picture>` elements (it appears to want you to [use an `<img>` element with `data` attributes for media queries](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes#how-to)) so you may want to research a lazy loading library that works with the `<picture>` element now that you (hopefully) understand why your implementation is not working.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did have the script, not only the HTML, but indeed the problem was the srcset messing with the data-src, I changed the srcset to data-srcset and it worked. Also I found some references [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840467/how-to-do-lazy-loading-image-with-srcset#:~:text=Note%20srcset%20is%20changed%20to,t%20made%20too%20much%20sense.&text=I%20simply%20switched%20it%20to,gets%20automatically%20calculated%20for%20you.)here